Modelderivative does not retrieve properties for linked models
I use /modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{3dViewGuid}/properties:query post query with queryIn filter, where I provide a massive of ["externalId", guid1, guid2, ...]. And asking for {"objectid", "name", "externalId"} fields.  
It works well with elements in the model, but does not retrieve parameters for linked models.
It used to work, but we noticed this problem some time ago.  
Zip file with linked .rvt models were transformed to sfv format.

[Get] /modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata (to get 3dViewGuid)
[Post] /modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{3dViewGuid}/properties:query
Parse response to get objectid for all provided externalId

Where am I wrong or may be something changed in APIs?

The decision is: 
You have to send the full made string that contains link instance guid and element guid by this pattern:
linkInstanceGuid/elementGuid

